# How to change column to list of values based on delimiter

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
SampleID    Chrom   Start       End         ID
HSB275      chr1    243216377   243219494   ENST00000366542|ENSG00000143702|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr1,243216377,243219494;ENST00000366543|ENSG00000143702|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr1,243216377,243219494
HSB274      chr10   952208      979839      ENST00000381466|ENSG00000205740|antisense|processed_transcript,chr10,971146,979839
HSB272      chr10   1046378     1047984     ENST00000381344|ENSG00000067064|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984;ENST00000491735|ENSG00000067064|processed_transcript|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984;ENST00000427898|ENSG00000067064|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984
HSB481      chr11   654157      655184      ENST00000527170|ENSG00000177030|nonsense_mediated_decay|protein_coding,chr11,654157,655184
```

What I want to do is reduce the `ID` column to just a list of "ENSGXXXXXXX" values, which are delimited by "," if there are multiple per row, so that it would look like the `Genes` column below:

**Desired outcome:**

```
SampleID    Chrom   Start       End         Genes
HSB275      chr1    243216377   243219494   ENSG00000143702,ENSG00000143702
HSB274      chr10   952208      979839      ENSG00000205740
HSB272      chr10   1046378     1047984     ENSG00000067064,ENSG00000067064,ENSG00000067064
HSB481      chr11   654157      655184      ENSG00000177030
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a fixed delimiter but using `strpslit` we can split the `ID` column on various delimiters  (`,`, `;`, `|`), then for each element keep only those values which start with "ENSG" and remove others.

```
sapply(strsplit(df$ID, ",|\\||;"), 
          function(x) toString(grep("^ENSG", x, value = TRUE)))


#[1] "ENSG00000143702, ENSG00000143702"                 
#[2] "ENSG00000205740"                                  
#[3] "ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064"
#[4] "ENSG00000177030"
```

Comment: Thank you! And what if I want to get the **unique** list for the `Genes` column?

Comment: @claudiadast I thought that you'll have that scenario. Just wrap it in `unique` then. `sapply(strsplit(df$ID, ",|\\||;"), 
          function(x) toString(unique(grep("^ENSG", x, value = T))))
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(Genes = map_chr(str_split(ID, ";"), ~toString(map(str_split(.x, "\\|"), 2)))) %>%
    select(-ID)
#  SampleID Chrom     Start       End
#1   HSB275  chr1 243216377 243219494
#2   HSB274 chr10    952208    979839
#3   HSB272 chr10   1046378   1047984
#4   HSB481 chr11    654157    655184
#                                              Genes
#1                  ENSG00000143702, ENSG00000143702
#2                                   ENSG00000205740
#3 ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064
#4                                   ENSG00000177030
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "SampleID    Chrom   Start       End         ID
HSB275      chr1    243216377   243219494   ENST00000366542|ENSG00000143702|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr1,243216377,243219494;ENST00000366543|ENSG00000143702|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr1,243216377,243219494
HSB274      chr10   952208      979839      ENST00000381466|ENSG00000205740|antisense|processed_transcript,chr10,971146,979839
HSB272      chr10   1046378     1047984     ENST00000381344|ENSG00000067064|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984;ENST00000491735|ENSG00000067064|processed_transcript|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984;ENST00000427898|ENSG00000067064|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984
HSB481      chr11   654157      655184      ENST00000527170|ENSG00000177030|nonsense_mediated_decay|protein_coding,chr11,654157,655184", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) #str_extract_all
df %>% group_by(SampleID) %>% #Use rowwise() if you do not like group_by
       mutate(Genes = paste(str_extract_all(ID, 'ENSG\\d+',simplify = T),collapse = ',')) %>% 
       select(-ID)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   SampleID [4]
SampleID Chrom     Start       End Genes                                          
<fct>    <fct>     <int>     <int> <chr>                                          
1 HSB275   chr1  243216377 243219494 ENSG00000143702,ENSG00000143702                
2 HSB274   chr10    952208    979839 ENSG00000205740                                
3 HSB272   chr10   1046378   1047984 ENSG00000067064,ENSG00000067064,ENSG00000067064
4 HSB481   chr11    654157    655184 ENSG00000177030
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

```
genes %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ID), funs(str_extract_all(., "ENSG[:digit:]*") %>% 
                                     str_replace_all("c|\"|\\(|\\)", "")))

    # A tibble: 4 x 5
  SampleID Chrom     Start       End ID                                               
  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                            
1 HSB275   chr1  243216377 243219494 ENSG00000143702, ENSG00000143702                 
2 HSB274   chr10    952208    979839 ENSG00000205740                                  
3 HSB272   chr10   1046378   1047984 ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064
4 HSB481   chr11    654157    655184 ENSG00000177030
```

This finds any pattern match with `ENSG<any length of numeric characters>`, then coerces the list to vector of relevant character strings, and tidies up any unwanted characters.

Though personally under the spirit of tidy data, I would put each "ID" on a seperate column, copying the relevant SampleID/Chrom/Start/End data.

Answer (score 0):

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "SampleID    Chrom   Start       End         ID
HSB275      chr1    243216377   243219494   ENST00000366542|ENSG00000143702|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr1,243216377,243219494;ENST00000366543|ENSG00000143702|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr1,243216377,243219494
HSB274      chr10   952208      979839      ENST00000381466|ENSG00000205740|antisense|processed_transcript,chr10,971146,979839
HSB272      chr10   1046378     1047984     ENST00000381344|ENSG00000067064|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984;ENST00000491735|ENSG00000067064|processed_transcript|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984;ENST00000427898|ENSG00000067064|protein_coding|protein_coding,chr10,1046378,1047984
HSB481      chr11   654157      655184      ENST00000527170|ENSG00000177030|nonsense_mediated_decay|protein_coding,chr11,654157,655184", header = T)
```

**my solution**

I define two functions which might be useful in future and to solve this task:

The first, `extract_matches`, extracts all matches for each element in `str.vec`. It returns a list of all matched substrings matching the pattern. It wraps `gregexpr` which returns only the position informations for the matches.

The second, `extract_matches_aggregating`, always returns a vector, since it concatenates all found matches using `sep=`. It is dependent on `extract_matches`.

You use these two functions to extract all ENSG IDs and linking them by ", ".

```
extract_matches <- function(pattern, str.vec) {
  Map(function(m, s) substring(s, m, m + attr(m, "match.length") - 1), gregexpr(pattern, str.vec), str.vec)
}

extract_matches_aggregating <- function(pattern, str.vec, sep = "; ") {
  sapply(extract_matches(pattern, str.vec), function(res_vec) {
           paste(res_vec, collapse = sep)})
}

df$ID <- extract_matches_aggregating(pattern = "ENSG\\d+", str.vec = df$ID, sep = ", ")
```

`df` is then:

```
  SampleID Chrom     Start       End
1   HSB275  chr1 243216377 243219494
2   HSB274 chr10    952208    979839
3   HSB272 chr10   1046378   1047984
4   HSB481 chr11    654157    655184
                                                 ID
1                  ENSG00000143702, ENSG00000143702
2                                   ENSG00000205740
3 ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064, ENSG00000067064
4                                   ENSG00000177030
```

This solution will be faster on huge tables than any solution using `strsplit` and `sapply` and `lapply`.